# Why does Executors.newCachedThreadPool throw java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException during submit

Tags: java, concurrency

Number of tasks (threads) submitted is also not huge in this test scenario.

Comment: Could you please refine your question? E.g. add a short testcase.

Comment: Sorry, there is not much code I can share due to IP reasons. In nut shell, I am calling submit with Callable<T> types. I am looking for potential scenarios this can happen.

Comment: Are you saying there is no specific scenario you are looking at, but instead would like to know of the hypothetical scenarios where this exception could be thrown?  if so, you should reword the question from 'Why does...' to 'When would...'

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll need to provide code samples of how you instantiate and call `submit` on the pool (IP should be a non-issue here as we don't need details of the internals of your `Callable` classes or anything like that).

Based on the information that you've given, you're almost certainly shutting down the executor service somewhere before submitting the callable to it.  Check if you make any calls to `shutdown` or `shutdownNow`, and if so ensure that you're not adding tasks after this point.

Beyond that, you may want to register your own implementation of `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler` in order to aid in debugging; its [rejectedExecution](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html#rejectedExecution(java.lang.Runnable,+java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor)) message will be called whenever the executor is unable to accept a task, so you could put some rudimentary state-inspection logic there to help you find the cause.

Comment: You were right; I found the code which was shutting down the executor pool; thanks

Answer (score 25):

I dont see anywhere in the invocation of the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` methods where a `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown.  There are only three cases where it appears to be thrown in Java 6:

- when calling `execute()` on a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and the maximum pool size has been reached.
- when calling `execute()` on a `ThreadPoolExecutor` at the same time that `shutdownNow`, and has essentially lost the race with the `shutdownNow` call.
- when trying to schedule execution of a runnable in a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` after the executor has been shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code that causes the exception:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor es = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
es.setCorePoolSize(2);    
es.setMaximumPoolSize(4); 
es.setKeepAliveTime(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
es.submit(runnableTask);
es.submit(runnableTask);
es.submit(runnableTask);
es.submit(callableTask);
es.submit(callableTask); // ===> RejectedExecutionException
es.shutdown(); // is not executed because of the exception before
```

The other Executor Services, i.e. `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)`, are submitted tasks are queued and executed later, but not throwing any exception.
What is special about `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` throwing an exception, when more than max tasks are submitted?